# using ngResource with webpack

Tags: angularjs, ecmascript-6, webpack, angular-resource

Good morning everyone,

I recently started using webpack on a new angular project. I really like it, very easy to use. I just have one problem, for now.
I'm trying to import ngResource to use on one of my modules, but not way I try works. I'm using webpack with babel loader (es6)

I tried each of the following ways:

```
//1
import ngResource from 'ng-resource'
angular.module('app', [ngResource])

//2
import 'ng-resource'
angular.module('app', ['ngResource'])


//3
import ngResource from 'ng-resource'
angular.module('app', [ngResource.name])
```

I tried even adding the following loader:

```
{
     test: /[\/]angular-resource\.js$/,
     loader: 'exports?angular.module(\'ngResource\')'
}
```

and then on my module:

```
angular.module('app', ['ngResource'])
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't figure it out :(

Thanks in advance,
Chaim

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was banging my head over this as well, it turns out you need

`npm install angular-resource` instead of `npm install ng-resource`

and then do:

`import ngResource from 'angular-resource'`

or one of the other methods you tried, they all work..

Answer (score 0):

you should import it as following:

```
import ngResource from 'angular-resource';
```

and then:

```
angular
  .module('app', [
    ngResource,
    ...
  ]);
```

The same rule to import any other angular core module

Comment: webpack doesn't regonize 'angular-resource'. it does however recognizes 'ng-resource', but I tried that in method 1, and it didn't work

Comment: did you install it via npm ? because webpack likes npm over bower, for bower you need to additionally configure webpack. You may also check this article http://goo.gl/dDSRvM in there they use ui-router as an example but the process is equivalent for ngResource.

Comment: i did install it with npm, not using bower

Comment: or use: import * as ngResource from 'angular-resource'

Answer (score 0):

this is right way:

```
var ngResource = require('ng-resource');
ngResource = ngResource(window, angular);

var yourmodule = angular.module( 'yourmodule', [ 'ngResource' ] )...
```

Comment: and you could use these in define